# How to use the PostgreSQL JSON array query ActiveRecord::Relation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I want to query ActiveRecord::Relation with *51* fields.
the data structure is like this:

```
matings: {"ids"=>[50, 51, 64]}
```

or

```
matings: {"ids"=>51}
```

If I do:

```
MouseColony.where("CAST(matings AS TEXT) LIKE ?", "%51%")

=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<MouseColony id: 604, animal_no: "a0008", animal_desc: "", gender: "M♂", source: "外购", animal_status: "配对", cage_id: nil, generation: 0, birth_date: "2018-12-25", weaning_date: "2019-01-15", disable_date: nil, received_date: "2019-03-20", created_at: "2019-06-03 02:45:03", updated_at: "2019-06-03 03:14:37", user_id: 1, strain_id: 1, mating_id: 64, litter_id: nil, purchase_mouse_number: "17203", age: 223, mating_quantity: 3, matings: {"ids"=>[50, 51, 64]}, genotype_id: 10, experiment_id: nil, experiment_date: nil, age_weeks: 32>, 
  #<MouseColony id: 624, animal_no: "a0028", animal_desc: "", gender: "F♀", source: "外购", animal_status: "配对", cage_id: nil, generation: 0, birth_date: "2018-12-25", weaning_date: "2019-01-15", disable_date: nil, received_date: "2019-03-20", created_at: "2019-06-03 02:50:07", updated_at: "2019-06-03 03:09:11", user_id: 1, strain_id: 1, mating_id: 51, litter_id: nil, purchase_mouse_number: "17138", age: 223, mating_quantity: 5, matings: {"ids"=>51}, genotype_id: 9, experiment_id: nil, experiment_date: nil, age_weeks: 32>
]>
```

I tried to use `MouseColony.where("CAST(matings ->> 'ids' AS TEXT) LIKE ?", "%51%")` or using `MouseColony.where("matings ->> 'ids' = ?", "51")`, but the result is such a `MouseColony Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "mouse_colonies".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (CAST(matings ->> 'ids' AS TEXT) LIKE '%51%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

I've also tried to use this:

```
MouseColony.where("matings #>> '{ids}' = ?", "51")
```

But still can't find any data.

I think my problem might be here: 
My models: mouse_colony.rb 
`store :matings, :accessors => [:ids], coder: JSON`
 and I storage record like this: 
``` @mouse_colony.matings[:ids] = [50, 51, 64]`` @mouse_colony.save ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the "contains" operator [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
MouseColony.where("matings->'ids' @> '?'", 51)
```

Comment: `MouseColony Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "mouse_colonies".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings->>'ids' @> '51') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text @> unknown
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings->>'ids' @> '51') L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "mouse_colonies".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings->>'ids' @> '51') LIMIT $1`

Comment: `class AddMatingsToMouseColony < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2] `
 
 `add_column :mouse_colonies, :matings, :jsonb `

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Rails 5.2.3 and Postgres 10/10

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I cloned the test project you created, I confirm that I can query the data. But I don't know why my project doesn't work, I will analyze it again. Thank you!

Comment: I think my problem might be here: 
My models: mouse_colony.rb `store :matings, :accessors => [:ids], coder: JSON`
and I storage record like this:
`@mouse_colony.matings[:ids] = [50, 51, 64]`   
`@mouse_colony.save`           What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I used your project to reproduce this problem. First create , I can query the data. but i using `rake db:reset`,  can't find any records. like this： `MouseColony Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "mouse_colonies".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings->'ids' @> '51') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: Because I used to be in my database? I just test

Comment: I export my database, the matings like this:
`"{\\"ids\\":[10,11]}"`
but correct should be `{"ids": [50, 51, 64]}`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `LIKE` operator like this:

```
MouseColony.where("matings::json->>'ids' LIKE ?", "%51%")
```

Comment: I tried this method but could not find any records.
`irb(main):001:0> MouseColony.where("matings::json->>'ids' LIKE ?", "%51%")
  MouseColony Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "mouse_colonies".* FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings::json->>'ids' LIKE '%51%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: That's weird, I duplicated part of your data and [it works for me](https://imgur.com/ZsnAZkX), are you sure the matings column is JSON? If you copy and paste this code `MouseColony.last.matings.class` what's the output? It should be `Hash`. Also, verify that you have data, ie, `MouseColony.count` should be greater than one and at least one with matings like this `matings: {"ids"=>[50, 51, 64]}` or this `matings: {"ids"=>51}`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this method, `MouseColony.last.matings.class` output: `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: `MouseColony.where("matings::json->>'ids' LIKE ?", "%51%").count
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mouse_colonies" WHERE (matings::json->>'ids' LIKE '%51%')
=> 0`